# How to update kdenlive(snap) 20.04 to 20.08

Tags: kdenlive

Please tell me how to update kdenlive(snap) 20.04 to 20.08.

[image: How to update Kdenlive 20.04 to 20.08.]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this link to the [snapstore](https://snapcraft.io/kdenlive), kdenlive has not been updated to 20.04 yet (as of 18.08.20), so there's nothing you can do. However, it will certainly be updated within a few days.

If you really need kdenlive 20.08 right now, you can either use the [appimage](https://kdenlive.org/en/download/), or the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable) (which is only available for Ubuntu 20.04).